# sed command - take value from spec file and assign it to variable in sh file

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sed

I have two files, spec file and sh file.

A variable in spec file holds a value. And I am looking to assign that variable's value to another variable in sh file.

spec file contains the following:

```
    HOSTID=10
```

and there is a variable in sh file :

```
    ACTIVE_HOSTID=
```

I used the following sed command in spec file.

```
sed "s/$HOSTID/ACTIVE_HOSTID/g" spec_file>sh_file
```

Could anyone help me with this?

EDIT :

My spec file looks like :

```
HOSTID=`ip addr | grep ether | awk '{print $2}' | head -n 1 | sed -e 's/\://g'`
```

My sh file looks like :

```
    ACTIVE_HOSTID=
    BACKUP_SERVER_HOSTID=
    EXTENDED_SUFFIX=
    EXTRA_SYSPROPERTIES=
```

Now I need to get the value for ACTIVE_HOSTID from HOSTID.

EDIT 2 :

I tried the following:

```
    sed -i "s/ACTIVE_HOSTID=.*/ACTIVE_HOSTID=HOSTID/" sh_file
```

It is replacing ACTIVE_HOSTID with the string "HOSTID" and not its value.
And if I use with the "$" like

```
    sed -i "s/ACTIVE_HOSTID=.*/ACTIVE_HOSTID=$HOSTID/" sh_file
```

ACTIVE_HOSTID is still empty

Comment: What is $HOSTID? Is this sed line running in a script? You aren't doing anything with variables, but you keep using that word. What does your `sh file` look like and how do you want it to look when you are done running whatever it is you want to run?

Comment: This sed is in my spec file. HOSTID and ACTIVE_HOSTID are the variables.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. If the `sed` command is in the spec file, why is it also reading the spec file as its input?

Comment: Is the spec file a script or a data file? Putting commands into a data file doesn't do anything.

Comment: What should be the output?  `ACTIVE_HOSTID=10` in the `sh_file`?  Is there a good reason not to modify the 'sh_file' to use something like `ACTIVE_HOSTID="$(sed -n '/HOSTID=\([0-9][0-9]*\)/s//\1/p spec_file)"` to set the variable from the 'spec_file'?  Can there be more than one HOSTID line in the spec_file?  Is the spec_file not available where the sh_file is run?  The problem isn't yet clear.

Comment: @Barmar it is a rpm spec file.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes ACTIVE_HOSTID=10 in the sh_file should be the output. This command is running in rpm spec file before installing the software.

Comment: What you've told us you have should work as-is so there's something about your code/data that you haven't told us so far. [edit] your question to show a [mcve] which means a spec file where you set HOSTID to a specific value and the last sed command currently in your question, and a sh file that you want to modify plus the result on the sh file of you running that spec file. Copy/paste the commands, input, and output into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in `spec_file` after the `HOSTID` assignment.

```
sed -i.bak "s/ACTIVE_HOSTID=.*/ACTIVE_HOSTID=$HOSTID/" sh_file
```

Your code was replacing the `ACTIVE_HOSTID=` part of the line, but you want to replace the part *after* that.

Comment: No, I assumed this would be in a new script that uses `spec_file`.

Comment: Is it possible to run it from the spec_file itself?

Comment: sed -i "s/ACTIVE_HOSTID=.*/ACTIVE_HOSTID=HOSTID/" sh_file                          I tried this but it is replacing ACTIVE_HOSTID with the string "HOSTID" and not its value. If I use your command it is creating another .bak file

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shown any sample Input_file so I am taking example here.

```
HOSTID=10
ACTIVE_HOSTID=17

cat Input_file
S00739A WT-10
S00739B WT-2
S00739D mt-1
S00739E mt-2
```

Then following code will change values from 10 to 17 in Input_file.

```
sed "s/$HOSTID/$ACTIVE_HOSTID/g"  Input_file
S00739A WT-17
S00739B WT-2
S00739D mt-1
S00739E mt-2
```

**EDIT:** If you are looking to import variables from different scripts(you mentioned sh file) and files into a new shell script/script, then following may help you to take variables from there to current script.

```
. ./script_name 
OR
source ./script_name
```

Now when you create a new script and do above for both spec and sh file(call their variables in this sed script) then you variables named HOSTID and ACTIVE_HOSTID will have value in them and you could use sed command then.

Comment: HOSTID and ACTIVE_HOSTID are not in the same file. They are in two different files. I want to run that sed command in spec file and it should change the ACTIVE_HOSTID value in sh file.

Comment: Still not clear, but 1 thing even they are coming from different file you can save their values from different files and could use these variables, I think that is why variables have been made to store the values and could be used in further code etc. Let us know more clearly so that we could help you in same then.

Comment: I have edited my question and added contents from both the files. Could you please look into it?

Comment: check my EDIT now and let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard with sed
You can try

```
exec 3<"sh file"
rm "sh file"
while read line
 do
  if [[ "$line" =~ "ACTIVE_HOSTID=" ]]
   then
    line=$(grep 'HOSTID=' spec_file)
    echo ACTIVE_"$line"
   else
    echo "$line"
  fi
done<&3>"sh file"
```